# How to clone textareas with cloneNode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clonenode

I have 2 tables, and with a button I want to clone the content from `tb_new` to `tb_made`:

```
var tab = document.getElementById('tb_new');
var clone=tab.getElementsByTagName('tr')[1].cloneNode(true);
var table = document.getElementById("tb_made"); 
table.appendChild(clone);
```

Everything is cloned fine, except one cell with a `textarea`.
How can I fix that?

Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/042ppskz/11).

Comment: Show us a snippet that can replays it, I've created [one](https://jsfiddle.net/3ohsoLzu/) but it works.

Comment: just make sure that tab.getElementsByTagName('tr')[1] means we selected the second tr and not the first

Comment: Sorry, here is a snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/042ppskz/11/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing in a `<textarea>` will only update its value, not its content.

To solve the issue you can do something like this:

```js
function add() {
    var tab = document.getElementById('tb_new');
    var textAreas = tab.getElementsByTagName("textarea");

    for (var i = 0; i < textAreas.length; ++i) {
        textAreas[i].innerHTML = textAreas[i].value;
    }

    var clone = tab.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].cloneNode(true);
    var table = document.getElementById('tb_made');
    table.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<table id="tb_new">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <textarea>Test</textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="add" onClick="add()">
<table id="tb_made">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```